# Unity 3D Does Not Apply Texture To Object Properly

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have got a problem with texturing an object in Unity 3D. I have made a simple object in 3Ds Max and inserted it into Unity and then tried to apply an image as texture but it does not apply the texture and it only changes the color of the object! This is the print screen:

[image: print screen]

As you can see I have got two models. One of them is made in 3Ds Max and does not apply the texture and the other one is made in Unity and it's a cube and it gets the texture correctly.

So what's going wrong here ? Not that I also changed the tiling and offset settings of model's shader but still nothing's changed at all! :(

Answer (score 1):

You didn't UV Unwrapped the 3d object before exporting to Unity3D.

To apply the textures on 3d mesh, any engine needs to know coordinates for texture, and this is called UV Mapping.

[WIKIPEDIA - UV_mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping)